# Threading face_detection on camera with opencv

Tags: c, multithreading, opencv

I am training to use thread on face,nose,eyes detection. Because, when I did not, the camera is working very slowly. I wrote this code. I can not find mistake in code. But when I compiled  it is giving exception

on taskCollection tab pChore->m_pFunction(pChore); error.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "cv.h"
    #include "highgui.h"
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    struct parameter_t{
        IplImage* capturedImg;
        CvHaarClassifierCascade* pCascade_face;
        CvMemStorage* storage;
    };

    void* threadface_func(void* parameter){

        CvSeq * detectRect_face;
        parameter_t *p =(parameter_t*)parameter;

        detectRect_face=cvHaarDetectObjects(p->capturedImg,p->pCascade_face,p->storage,1.15, 3, 0,cvSize(50,50));

        for(int i=0;i<(detectRect_face ? detectRect_face->total:0); i++ )
            {
                CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(detectRect_face, i); 
                CvPoint pt1 = { r->x, r->y }; 
                CvPoint pt2 = { r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height }; 
                cvRectangle(p->capturedImg, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1,8, 0); 

            }
        return 0;
    }

    int main ()
    {
            CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
            IplImage* capturedImg;
            int resCount = 1;
            int flags = CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH;

            CvHaarClassifierCascade * pCascade_face;
            pthread_t threadface;


            pCascade_face = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *)cvLoad("C:/Users/Furkan/Desktop/Computer Vision/Programlar/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
            cvNamedWindow("FaceDetection");

            while (true)
            {

                CvMemStorage * storage = 0;
                capturedImg = cvQueryFrame(capture);
                storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

                parameter_t my_parameters;
                my_parameters.capturedImg=capturedImg;
                my_parameters.storage=storage;
                my_parameters.pCascade_face=pCascade_face;

                int k=pthread_create(&threadface,0,threadface_func,(void*)&my_parameters);

                if(k!=0)
                {
                    printf("Create thread failed! error");
                    return 1;
                }

                cvShowImage("FaceDetection", capturedImg);

            }

        cvDestroyWindow("FaceDetection");

        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return 0;
    }
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

1. the IplImages you get from the capture are pointing to videodriver-memory. to use them in another thread, youve got to clone() them. (i see, that you're even trying to draw into that).
2. you're generating new threads at an absurd high rate there, without ever waiting for one to finish
3. i can't see any lock/mutex in your code

please reconsider using multiple threads at all. at least, it won't work like this

(seems, that your opencv version & your api use could need an upgrade, too .. )